# Windows batch script - place strict limits on results of findstr

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to write a script that uses FINDSTR to look for keywords in a text file.  Given the following command:

```
findstr /s "item1" source.txt >> output.txt
```

How do I ensure that the result only pulls those lines containing "item1" and not for example "item 14"?

I tried /l and /C: to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the regex word boundry anchor.

```
findstr /sr "\<item1\>" source.txt >> output.txt
```

FINDSTR will detect the regex metacharacters and automatically treat the search string as a regular expression. But it is better to explicitly specify a regex search with the `/R` option.

The FINDSTR implementation of the word boundry anchor is very non-standard, but I think it will work for you. See [What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868/1012053) for more information. The relevent portion of the answer is near the end in a section titled ***"Regex word boundary"***.

Comment: Outstanding answer!  Thank you very much!